# Unwanted output is being printed after the correct output is being displayed

Tags: c, centos

I came up with a method of changing infix to postfix notation using recursion, to test the basic program (which didn't contain the intended part) I just printed the string which was to be evaluated.

Example: if the input is "*A+(B-C)*" the output will be just "*A+B-C*" --> which is *B-C* will be printed as a separate operand by using recursion whenever the program encounters "**(**". On encountering **(** it sends the rest of the string in recursion and print the elements till it encounters **)** - it sends the no. of elements traversed including the **)** encountered as return value.

Now I am satisfied with the algo but there is some weird stuff getting printed **after** the output is printed (which seems to be correct), please have a look and help me:

```
/*THE INPUT SHOULD HAVE NO MISSING PARENTHESES (IF THERE ARE ANY) */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int fun(char c[])
{
    int len=strlen(c),i=0;

    while(i!=len)
    {
        if(c[i]=='(')
        {
            char cpy[len-i];
            strcpy(cpy,c+i+1);
            ++i;
            //RECURSIVE FUNCTION WHICH RETURNS THE NO. OF ELEMTS IT HAS TRAVERSED INCLUDING ")"
            i+=fun(cpy);
        }
        if(c[i]==')')
        {
            return 1+i;
        }
        //INSTEAD OF PRINTING, STACK OPERATION MAY BE USED TO GET THE POSTFIX NOTATION
        printf("%c",c[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    //EVEN THIS UNDERLYING COMMENTED INPUT CAN BE USED
    //i=fun("(A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M)");  
    i=fun("(((A+B)))");
    printf("\n-------------------\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

Now the error which is being thrown when two different inputs are used (one being the commented input):

[image: OUTPUT IS IN RED, IT IS THE INTENDED OUTPUT]

[image]

---

The compiler being used is **gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)**

Comment: Did you null terminate everything?

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice in the loop. Can easily miss the `len` it is compared to.

Comment: Actually not even twice, but also adding some recursive result to it. The logic is a bit convoluted to be analyzed by looking. Debug it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that is by design. Output is correct, I am worried about what happens after the `---------` line is printed.

Comment: No, output is not correct. Otherwise you won't be here. But the fact you have strange stuff after the last `printf` is interesting, yes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've checked it on paper and even the print statement after the functiion call from main() is working fine.

Comment: It is not working fine and you can see it. Somehow you are corrupting the `-----` string and overwriting it's terminator (one, the most obvious thing that could happen..).

Comment: `char cpy[len-i];` seems to be the culprit although the code is obscure. Suggest `char cpy[len*2];`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Since most compilers put literal strings in non-writable memory, corrupting that string seems unlikely.

Comment: @Barmar In fact, most of the times I dealt with it it, the actual memory was writable. I can't think of other mechanism to cause this behavior. Perhaps corrupting the return address of `printf`? But I don't see how.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Are you sure about that? One of the common reasons for segmentation violation errors is trying to modify a string literal. Lots of SO questions are because of that.

Comment: @Barmar Can't tell for sure. I am mostly dealing with embedded platforms where *I* define the accessibility of the memory regions :)

Comment: In the old world, **ROM** is definitely not writeable.

Comment: By the way, running this code on [ideone](https://ideone.com/Dngd1q) is giving "runtime error", which is expected...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm talking about Unix and Windows.

Comment: I have just run few iterations in the debugger. Your `i` is definitely going out of bounds of your string. It's up to you to debug. Your `while` loop is never terminating and I suspect the `------` thing is printed by accident by the `printf("%c",c[i]);` line somehow.

Comment: I think you'd improve the chances of the code working if you use an `if (…) { … } else if (…) { … } else { … }` structure in the loop.  At the moment, you increment `i` too often when processing a `(`.  You also really don't need to make a copy of the string; you could simply pass the pointer to the correct location into the recursive call.

Comment: Yep. Just confirmed on my system that `-----` is printed character-wise by the `printf` in the loop. Which makes sense, as `c` is pointing to a string literal in the aforementioned RO memory, adjacent to another string literal `\n-------\n`

Comment: @EugeneSh. it is by design to let `i` go out of bounds, the problem was with something different.

Comment: Come on, I told you exactly what the problem is in my very first comment. And explained why you see what you see in the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313923/unwanted-output-is-being-printed-after-the-correct-output-is-being-displayed#comment89605433_51313923), you simply need to make sure that only one of the three paragraphs of code in the loop body is executed on each iteration.  Here's an adaptation that works correctly on both the sample expressions in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int fun(char c[])
{
    int len = strlen(c), i = 0;

    while (i != len)
    {
        if (c[i] == '(')
        {
            char cpy[len - i];
            strcpy(cpy, c + i + 1);
            ++i;
            i += fun(cpy);
        }
        else if (c[i] == ')')
        {
            return 1 + i;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", c[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

static void evaluate(char *expr)
{
    printf("expression: [%s]\n", expr);
    int i = fun(expr);
    printf("\ni = %d\n-------------------\n", i);
}

int main(void)
{
    evaluate("(((A+B)))");
    evaluate("(A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M)");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
expression: [(((A+B)))]
A+B
i = 9
-------------------
expression: [(A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M)]
A+B*C-D/E*K-R+M
i = 21
-------------------
```

---

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313923/unwanted-output-is-being-printed-after-the-correct-output-is-being-displayed/51314729?noredirect=1#comment89606270_51314736) by [infinite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8977486/infinite):

> When `((A+B)^C-(D*E)/F)` is used as input, the `else if` clause will skip `^`.

That is not what I found when I tested it, both on the code above (adding a new call to `evaluate()`) or on the code below.   This is a slightly compacter version of the code, which forgoes copying the string, and it produces the correct output too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int fun(char c[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while (c[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (c[i] == '(')
            i += fun(&c[i+1]) + 1;
        else if (c[i] == ')')
            return 1 + i;
        else
        {
            printf("%c", c[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

static void evaluate(char *expr)
{
    printf("expression: %zu [%s]\n", strlen(expr), expr);
    int i = fun(expr);
    printf("\ni = %d\n-------------------\n", i);
}

int main(void)
{
    evaluate("(((A+B)))");
    evaluate("(A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M)");
    evaluate("A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M");
    evaluate("((A+B)^C-(D*E)/F)");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
expression: 9 [(((A+B)))]
A+B
i = 9
-------------------
expression: 21 [(A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M)]
A+B*C-D/E*K-R+M
i = 21
-------------------
expression: 19 [A+B*(C-D/E*(K-R))+M]
A+B*C-D/E*K-R+M
i = 19
-------------------
expression: 17 [((A+B)^C-(D*E)/F)]
A+B^C-D*E/F
i = 17
-------------------
```

The caret is not dropped in the the expression `((A+B)^C-(D*E)/F)`; it handles 1, 2 or 3 consecutive `)` correctly (on correct input).  Life may get messy if the input is malformed; this is not robust code in the face of errors.  But I believe the core is sound on valid input, which is basically any string with a balanced, optionally nested, set of open and close parentheses.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I was thinking that your suggestion of `else if` will fail in case of two consecutive `)` but it didn't, I am analyzing your solution and I've found the problem which was a bit different, now it works perfectly. :)

Comment: Yes, when `((A+B)^C-(D*E)/F)` is used as input, the `else if` clause will skip `^`.

Comment: As noted in the extended answer, the caret `^` is not skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble I found was, instead of `while(i!=len)` it should've been `while(i<len)`.

In the most primitive recursive stage (when **(** is encountered for the first time in the original string) **i** becomes larger than **len** when all the return values come back from the deepest recursion, rest of the implementation is correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yea, I am working on a subprogram which detects if there is some missing parentheses in the input, it fails only in case of missing parentheses, example  `A+B-(C+D)*E/F` works fine.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong — so I've removed it.  Using `(i < len)` and `(i != len)` are essentially equivalent when things go right — both stop when `len` is equal to `i`.  Using `<` has the benefit that if `i` is incremented to be bigger than `len`, the loop still stops, whereas `!=` will continue merrily reading data from goodness knows where.  OTOH, it has the demerit that you won't spot the problem if you're not looking carefully.  It is defensive programming to use `<`, and that is generally beneficial.  It could be backed up by `assert(i == len);` after the loop.